# Как подключить ag-Grid в rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В assets/javascripts вставил два файла ag-grid.js и example.js

В **example.js** содержится

```
// specify the columns
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
    {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
    {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
];

// specify the data
var rowData = [
    {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
];

// let the grid know which columns and what data to use
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData
};

// wait for the document to be loaded, otherwise
// ag-Grid will not find the div in the document.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
    var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

    // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
    new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

В **applications.js** содержится

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require ag-grid
//= require example
//= require_tree .
```

В **apllication.html.erb** содержится

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Biblios</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'ag-grid': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'example': 'reload' %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

В консоли вижу как либы подгружаются, однако страница пустая. На ней нет никаких данных. Что я делаю не так?*

Comment: Откройте консоль браузера, посмотрите есть ли там ошибки. Посмотрите на запросы, совершаемые при загрузке страницы, есть ли ошибки там.

Comment: ошибок нет в том то и дело

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/Radzhab/ag-test/src вот репозиторий.

Comment: Проследите, выполняется ли приведённый в вопросе код (`example.js`) вообще.

Comment: вставил код из example.js в консоль хрома - после выполнения пишет undefined

Comment: Решилось все. Оказывается грид был на странице - но его стили не подхватились. Пришлось ручками изменить через css ,его размеры